# How to generate more random map in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, noise, terrain

I want to generate 2D map with landscape for my game. Now I am using Perlin noise to do that.

```
private List<List<int>> GenerateTerrain()
{
    var result = new List<List<int>>();
    for (var x = 0; x < mapSize; x++)
    {
        var row = new List<int>();
        for (var y = 0; y < mapSize; y++)
        {
            row.Add(GenerateNoise(x, y));
        }
        result.Add(row);
    }
    return result;
}

private int GenerateNoise(int x, int y)
{
    var rawNoise = Mathf.PerlinNoise((x - noiseOffsetX) / noiseScale, (y - noiseOffsetY) / noiseScale);
    var clampedNoise = Mathf.Clamp(rawNoise, 0, 1);
    if (clampedNoise > 0.85)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else if (clampedNoise > 0.75)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (clampedNoise > 0.60)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (clampedNoise > 0.35)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Here in `GenerateNoise` imagine that `0` is the lowest height of the map (bottom of the ocean for example) and `4` is the highest (mountain).

The problem here is that map generates "evenly" - if there is a mountain (`4`) it will be sorrounded  by lower mountains (`3`) and they will be surrounded by plains (`2`) and etc. But I want more random generation - cliffs with growing height (from `0` to `4`) from the east, for example, and then immediately dropping to `0` on west; or just mountain range (`4`) in ocean (`0`).

Is it possible to do? Maybe there is some another type of noise which can do that?

I have an idea of preparing some structures somewhere and then with some chance generating them. But the problem here is that I need to prepare a lot of structures, especially for mountain ranges. And I still don't fully know how to properly integrate them in terrain after base generation.

Comment: Yes. Keep going. So if x is 10. Go to 20.

Comment: @BugFinder what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe look into how Minecraft handles its procedural generation: Chunks of the map are of a random "biome" which have different systems in place to generate the terrain, e.g. a "hilly" terrain works different than a "mountain" terrain. Build a few generators, make sure they properly blend together when next to each other and then you can generate whatever you want and extend it as much as you like.

Comment: I recommend trial and error, there are plenty, massive amounts of different noise patterns out there. Make a tool that makes it easy to switch being different noises so you have an easy time comparing them.